# Silverlight WebApp on Non-Windows platforms,

Tags: silverlight, cross-browser

I have decided to use a silverlight player on my ASP.NET WebApp ,I haven't used silverlight before ,let me know would the player be able to run on Non-Windows platforms (such as Mac or Ubuntu) inside the browser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight is a browser-plugin. There are versions available for both Windows and Mac OS (see teh system requirements [listed here](http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/Get-Started/Install/Default.aspx)). Your end-user will be directed to download the plugin for their specific OS if they do not have it installed. Once installed your application will run in exactly the same way on Mac and Windows.

For Linux there is [Moonlight](http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight), which gives Silverlight plugin support, but I don't know how mature this is yet.

Comment: ok great Just searched and found this "you should install the Moonlight plug-in instead of Silverlight. This is a free, open-source version of Silverlight which runs on Linux. Moonlight is not installed by default in Ubuntu."

Comment: If the user installed Moonlight will my Silverlight App behave exactly as it would in Win O/S ?

Comment: It is quite unlikely. Moonlight is not a complete Silverlight implementation. See their website for details.